# How to perform a major update on typo3

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, updates, typo3-extensions

I have a website running on typo3 version 10. I want to do an upgrade to version 12, but I'm struggling on where to start. There is no composer package installed on the machine, so I guess typo3 was installed in legacy mode, and I also have a bunch of extensions installed on the system, some of them are from the TER and some of them are custom extensions. The documentation (and what I could find online) is not very clear. Is there a clear and detailed step by step strategy on how to do this update?

I have tried running the extensions checker, but this somehow seems to freeze after analyzing the first few extensions, also the website crashes when I do this and is not accessible anymore

Comment: Have a look into the official documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/12.4/en-us/Major/Index.html

Comment: @Chris this was the first thing I did, unfortunately all the documentation is using composer ..

Comment: Without a doubt, which kind of installation your instance is based on, it will become difficult... Maybe you're looking for a symlinked upgrade? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/12.4/en-us/Legacy/Index.html#major-upgrades-symlink-the-core
If you are confident with composer (and your environment does allow it), the upgrade would be a good moment to switch (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/main/en-us/MigrateToComposer/Index.html)